# $(...).modal is not a function jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Tengo un Gridview en el cual implemento el evento onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" para mostrar otro gridview en un modal con el codigo de la columna seleccionada, he depurado el codigo y a pesar de que no marca error no me abre el modal.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" ...>   
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="codigo" HeaderText="codigo" SortExpression="codigo" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" SortExpression="Nombre" />
...
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Mas" />
</Columns>  
</asp:GridView>

 <!-- MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="MiModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"  data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg " role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">    
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"  
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" allowpaging="True" Font-Size="X-Small" Font-Bold="True" PageSize="10" ShowFooter="True">   
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="codigo" HeaderText="codigo" SortExpression="codigo" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Cargo" HeaderText="Cargo" SortExpression="Cargo" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Abono" HeaderText="Abono" SortExpression="Abono"  />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Saldo" HeaderText="Saldo" SortExpression="Saldo" />       
</Columns>      
</asp:GridView>        
 ...
```

```html
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Mas_Click();
}

protected void Mas_Click()
{
 con.Open();
 try
 {
 GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
 int cod = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Text);
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "none", "<script>$('#MiModal').modal('show');</script>", false);

string query="select * from tabla where codigo=@codigo";
SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
cm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", cod);
cm1.CommandTimeout = 0;
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cm1);
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
da1.Fill(dt1);
GridView2.DataSource = dt1;
GridView2.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception er)
 {
  er.ToString();
 }
 con.Close();        
}
```

[image: Gridview1]

Use este codigo en C#

```html
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ModalView", "<script> $('#MiModal').modal({ show: true });</script>", false);
```

Pero me da este error en la consola : 
uncaught typeerror $(...).modal is not a function jquery
Espero haberme dado a entender.

Comment: Como es el codigo del evento del boton? deberias recibir la fila que presionaste ahi

Comment: en realidad todo se carga en el protected void Page_Load porque nose como recuperar ese valor en diferentes metodos :c

Comment: entonces eso.. cada boton deberia ir a un evento y devolver sobre que fila se presiono.. muestra como armas la grilla...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para seleccionar un codigo se hace uso del `DataKeys` del `GridView`, para esto debes asignar el `DataKeyNames`, en esa propiedad defines cual es el valor que sera la key de cada row.

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" DataKeyNames="codigo" ...>
```

Entonces usas en el boton un CommandName="Mas" o CommandName="Select" el que mas guste, pro usaras el  evento `RowCommand`

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Mas")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        int cod = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value); 

        //resto codigo

    }
}
```

Es importante notar como se selecciona la row que lanza el evento con el `e.CommandArgument` para luego obteer el codigo asociado a esa row por medio del `DataKeys`

Comment: Agregue el codigo al gridview1 y al boton para abrir el modal pero no entra al evento                                                                                          
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="codigo"    asp:LinkButton CommandName="Mas" runat="server" Text="Mas..."

Comment: pero como implementas el modal? porque haya algunos que no funcionan si haces un post al servidor, requiere que lo resuelvas usando javascript

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta